# Not Quite a Pipe Dream

Tags: visual, geometry

[image]

## Goal

Complete the connection between the two red pipes using any of the pipe shapes provided below, using as few pieces as possible.

This puzzle can be completed by placing just four extra pieces.

**Pipe Shapes**

[image]

**Information**

- The grid is [14 x 14 units](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdHZE.png)
- Pipes are 1 unit in diameter.

**Rules**

- You must have a continuous connection between each red pipe (A valid connection is achieved by aligning the ends of the pipes parallel to each other)
- You must not make any adjustments to any of the pipes that have already been placed (the two red and two green pipes).
- You must not place any pipes fully or partially outside of the grid.
- You may make a connection with the green pipes already placed.
- You may rotate any pipe you place, in increments of 90°.
- You may place the same shape pipe more than once.
- You are not required to use every pipe shape.

[Valid solution example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NyFH.png)  (six pieces).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Aha! The solution:

> Side view
>
> ```
>  -----YYYY-----
>  RBBBYYGGYYBBBR
> ```
>
> Top view
>
> ```
>  ------GGG-----
>  RBBBYYYYYYBBBR
>  -----GGG------
> ```
>
> 3D view:
>  
>  [image]

Comment: If only I could post a nice image instead...

Comment: Oh! I get it now. Clever. Yes, It would be nice to have a good picture of it.

Comment: @Jaap Such a nice 'aha' moment when you see it

Comment: Does it work? I thought the greens would be three wide in your sideways view

Comment: @Avi The text rendering does not show three dimensions.

Comment: Oh, that's *sneaky* :)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis [Like this?](https://i.imgur.com/k0abL3x.png) (@DanielMathias Feel free to use this image in your answer)

Comment: @Ambo100 Very nice!

Comment: I've edited @Ambo100's image into the answer because I was struggling to understand what you'd done. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: What program are you using to make the render?

Comment: @BruceWayne I use Blender because it's free and I can just about model basic things with it.

Comment: Ehhhh this feels like a trick question puzzle :/ It specifically says you can't go outside the grid, yet the answer involved going 3D.